# MVC4 Incorrect model error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

Hi I getting this error:
**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DBModel.Telemarketing]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TWeb.Models.LoginModel'**

In  _Layout.cshtml file i have

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

this partial login view is rendered in div on _layout page (it`s hides/shows with javaScripts )

```
@model TWeb.Models.LoginModel
```

Then I have "Telemarketings" controller having view:

```
public class TelemarketingController : Controller
{
    private Entities db = new Entities();

    //
    // GET: /Telemarketing/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Telemarketings.ToList());
    }
```

When I click link  in _Layout page

```
@Html.ActionLink("Telemarketingas", "Index", "Telemarketing", new{area="" },new{ })
```

It throws an error written in top of the post.

I am new in MVC, please help me.

Comment: If your partial view expect a Model, you have to pass it then you call  `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", model)`

Comment: problem is he is calling the partial from _layout. He should make it @Html.Action("_LoginPartial") so that it can GENERATE a model

Comment: you need to use @model IEnumerable<TWeb.Models.LoginModel> in your view inorder to work with that

Comment: To "Dave A". When I tried use action, I was getting  error: **Insufficient stack to continue executing the program safely. This can happen from having too many functions on the call stack or function on the stack using too much stack space.**

Comment: Ok, please expand. Which method did you use? if it was an action partial, did you create a controller action for it and instantiate and pass back a value? please add your new code (controller action and view to your answer so I can see it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem 1)** Your Partial requires a model, and you're not passing one.
proper syntax: `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Model.LoginModel)`

**problem 2)** _layout, as far as I know, can't have a Model passed

**Solution 1:**
Use an ActionPartial. AcionPartials are called similarly,

```
@Html.Action("/Tools/_LoginPartial").
```

The difference is they have an ActionMethod Associated which can return a Model

```
   public ActionResult _LoginPartial()
    {

          LoginModel Model= new LoginModel();
          //populate Model from whatever

         return View(Model);

    }
```

**Option 2:**
Pass a LoginModel object to a Viewbag

```
Viewbag.LoginModel = new LoginModel();
```

and reference the Viewbag in your _layout's Partial

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", Viewbag.LoginModel)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "_LoginPartial" expects "LoginModel" model, but since you're not giving it any, Razor engine sets its model to the current view model ("db.Telemarketings.ToList()").

All you have to do is somehow set its model, probably like so:

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial", new LoginModel())
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way was to remove model declaration from Login Div :).

Comment: yeah, if you don't need the model, that's the easiest way. calling it a night now. If this method works for you, great. If you need help with another, publish the work you've done and I'd be happy to go over it with you tmrw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
 @Html.Partial("Partial page", new ModelFroLogin())
```

Comment: this would work if his partial takes an empty Model. If it doesn't he is out of luck.

Comment: use this in partial @model TWeb.Models.LoginModel